# Reverse Borel Cantelli

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

My question is regarding the Borel Cantelli Lemmas, what can we say about their reverse statements?

$X_{i}$ independent in what follows.

For example say $P(X_{n}>n$ i.o$)=0 $ can we say $\sum P(X_{n}\geq n) < \infty$ ? by some reverse BC.2 lemma?

Comment: Yes. If $E_i$ are independent events, then $\sum P(E_i)<\infty$ if and only if $P(E_n\text{ i.o.})=0$, so the reverse implications also hold.

Comment: and the same for B.C.1?